# SQL Developer- Session startup script

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to have every session in my SQL Developer to be set to the GMT timezone. Is there a way to setup a session startup script in SQL Developer for this?

Answer (score 12):

You can create a script file, e.g. `C:\Temp\startup.sql`, containing:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'GMT';
```

Then go to the Preferences, from the Tools menu, and go to the top-level Database item in the panel on the left, and put the path to your file in 'filename for connection startup script' text box:

[image]

You can change other settings in your script as well, if they can't be set in the Preferences->Database->NLS section.

The settings are only picked up when you open a new connection - they don't seem to be reapplied when you reconnect or when you open a new SQL Worksheet under an existing connection.

When you connect the 'script output' window will say:

```
session SET altered.
```

In 4.0.1 anyway, but apparently not in 4.0.2; and if you then do something like:

```
select current_timestamp from dual;
```

then you'll see the GMT time regardless of your PC's locale settings:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                 
-----------------------------------
06-MAY-14 11.23.42.593143000 GMT
```

with the script, versus in my case this without:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                 
-----------------------------------
06-MAY-14 12.25.09.925466000 EUROPE 
/LONDON
```

This is tested in version 4.0.1.14 and 4.0.2.15; I think it's always been possible but I'm not able to check previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well and have an alternative solution.  I noticed this section of the Preferences

"Database" -> "NLS"

[image: Preferences->Database->NLS settings]

This shows some date/time formats.  In my case the "default" for "Date Format" was "DD-MON-YY".  I updated it to something more accurate and it then displays dates as I specified.

It does not show any output during the connection process but DOES 'alter the session'.