# Make new worksheets open with a default command/text in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I was wondering if there is a way to configure Oracle SQL Developer to open every new worksheet with some default query/command/text in it.

I've been looking in properties for a while, and googling it, but I found nothing.

Comment: Are you just trying to [configure the session as you connect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493422/266304), or do you actually want to see a script which you can then choose to run or replace?

Comment: The latter, although the link you provided is actually pretty useful for a very specific problem I have that I thought this could be a solution to. Thank you!